# Add a Custom Value in AbstractOrder on Hybris Commerce - AddtoCartFunction

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to add a custom value for the addtocart function in Hybris Commerce b2c. Is a boolean in with a checkbox.

I've add the bol custom value in core-items.xml but now I need to get that value when the checkbox is selected before press the addToCart Button and then show that value in the checkout page.

I thing it's not a short task, but I just want to understand the data flow for this kind of process, that's the complex part.

If someone have time to explain something, it will be grate! Thanks !

```
<form:form method="post" id="addToCartForm" class="add_to_cart_form" action="${addToCartUrl}">
<div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input path="trasiego" onclick="ACC.productDetail.enableMinusBtn()" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="trasiego">
        <form:checkbox path="trasiego" value="true"/>
    <spring:theme code="product.pdp.pedidoTrasiego"/>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" maxlength="3" size="1" id="qty" name="qty" class="qty js-qty-selector-input" value="1">
<input class = "js-simulate-validate-link" type="hidden" name="productCodePost" value="${fn:escapeXml(product.code)}"/>
        <ycommerce:testId code="simulateButton">
                    <button id="simulateButton" type="button" data-error-simulate-url="${fn:escapeXml(simulatePopup)}" data-simulate-title="<spring:theme code="text.simulate"/>" class="btn btn-default  btn-block js-add-to-cart" disabled=disabled">
                        <spring:theme code="basket.simulate"/>
                    </button>
        </ycommerce:testId>
        <ycommerce:testId code="addToCartButton">
            <button id="addToCartButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" disabled=disabled>
                <spring:theme code="basket.buy"/>
            </button>
            <br>
        </ycommerce:testId>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points below if you find it helpful,

> I've add the bol custom value in core-items.xml......

A little confused when I read above statement and hence wanted to put that it is against the standard practices to touch OOB extensions code base. Instead, you should be generating custom extension and extend/update Item in your project $extension-items.xml

> I need to get that value when the checkbox is selected before press the addToCart Button and then show that value in the checkout page.

You can achieve it with following steps :

**Step 1 -** In your project extension **$extension-items.xml**, add a new boolean attribute to **AbstractOrder**

```
<itemtype code="AbstractOrder" autocreate="false" generate="false" >
         <attributes>
                <attribute qualifier="code" type="java.lang.Boolean">
                        <persistence type="property" />
                </attribute>
         </attribute>
</itemtype>
```

**Step 2 -** Run ***ant clean all***

**Step 3 -** In you project storefront extension, add a checkbox in the Jsp/Tag file

**Step 4 -** If you want to persist the selection of this value on select/deselect of this checkbox, you can write an onClick() event in corresponding JS file.
In your case you can use 
/$storefornt-extension/web/webroot/WEB-INF/_ui-src/responsive/lib/ybase-0.1.0/js/**acc.cart.js**

**Step 5 -** Create corresponding handler in Controller (MVC). You may use **AddToCartController.java** or CartPageController as per your need

**Step 6 -** In corresponding facade --> service, save new field value to model

**Step 7 -** In **AbstractOrderPopulator** or **CartPopulator**, map your new field to fill it back into CartData from item model. And same can be used on next page for view.

With this your field value will be persisted & fetched to transfer between various hybris layers and you can use corresponding data object.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must disclose that it's your site*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).